# Operations with orthogonal matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthogonal-matrices

I have the following problem in linear algebra:

> Let $n = 1,3,5,7,9,\dots$ and an orthoginal matrix $C$ (with dimensions
>   $n\times n$) with $\det C=1$. Prove that:
>
> $$C^T  (C-I) = (I-C) ^T$$

I am aware of that for any orthogonal matrix, the transpose matrix is equal to the inverse one, but still I face difficulty in proving the above.
I would appreciate your quidance.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: On either side of the equality sign there is a parenthesis with an operation begging to be done to it. On one side a multiplication and on the other a transpose. What happens if you carry those out?

Comment: The restriction to odd $n$ is not necessary. This is true for all $n$.

Answer (score 2):

For any orthogonal matrix $C$,

$$C^T(C-I)=C^TC-C^T=I-C^T=(I-C)^T$$